# How get image pixel coordinate with `object-fit: contain`

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently displaying images with a `object-fit: contain` attribute, to be sure that aspect ratio is preserved and full image is displayed.

However, now, I need to react on click on this image, and get the coordinate of the clicked point relatively to the image origin.

Is there a way to do that? Or should I recompute the real position offset myself?

Comment: You will have to calculate the coordinates yourself

Answer (score 1):

@mousetail seems to be right, I found nothing else but my own code. It only works in the case of `object-fit: contain` with the default `object-position` value.

```js
    const image = document.querySelector('img')
    const matrix = new DOMMatrix()

    // First, center the image
    const elementCenter = new DOMPoint(image.clientWidth / 2, image.clientHeight / 2)
    const imageCenter = new DOMPoint(image.naturalWidth / 2, image.naturalHeight / 2)
    matrix.translateSelf(elementCenter.x - imageCenter.x, elementCenter.y - imageCenter.y)

    // And now zoom
    // Containing the object take the minimal zoom
    const zoom = Math.min(image.clientWidth / image.naturalWidth, image.clientHeight / image.naturalHeight)
    matrix.scaleSelf(zoom, zoom, 1, imageCenter.x, imageCenter.y)

    // Have fun
```

In the end, if you want to convert a point (e.g. from a `MouseEvent`), then you'll have to apply the reverse matrix on it:

```js
const point = new DOMPoint(12, 13)
const imagePoint = matrix.inverse().transformPoint(point)
```

Note that this transformation should be applied **after** the transformation from `transform` CSS attribute on the image itself.